# How to switch SQL server authentication based application to Windows based authentication app?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have developed an application which connects to database using SQL server authentication. While installation setup asks for admin credentials (For SQL server authentication) and create a new user (application specific). Setup needs admin credentials for creating specific user only. Setup also creates a database and map this database to newly created user. Now requirement changes to support MIXED mode authentication (Windows and SQL server both). It means, while installation setup will have option to select Windows mode or SQL mode. User can select either of Windows or SQL. If SQL is selected, she will have to provide username and password. My questions are:

1- If user selects WINDOWS mode, do I need to create application specific user? If yes, please guide how to create new user.

2- In the whole application, I have used connection string with "username" (application specific user created while setup installation) and "password". Do I need to create another connection string to serve the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] No you don't have to. You may, and it will work but this is not required. In Windows authentication  the process will provide credentials to SQL server of the user that currently runs the code. In most cases this will be the user that started a process. You can change the user of each thread, if needed, see [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx). But I would recommend not to, as this significantly complecate things.

In most cases you deploy your app as a service, Windows service or IIS application. It then runs under specific Windows system accounts, which you have to allow on the SQL server.

If you don't use Windows system accounts, you will face problems with password expiration, storing password securely, unathorised usage of the user name to run other executables.

It's trivial to add a user to Windows, just search for: *how to add a user account to Windows [Version Edition]*, but consider using system accounts first (such as Local Service, Network Service).

[2] I would recommend refactoring your application so that you refer to connection string by the name.

---

You would want to separate configuration management from executable. I.e. one application prepares configuration, another uses it. Such as, installer writes config string, application uses config string and application doesn't care what's inside as long as it allows access to the database.

Comment: Thanks oleksii. Suggested solution sounds good. What are possible modifications if there is only windows mode authentication available on user machine?

Comment: You will need to add a user to the authorised database users. I am not sure if this can be done programmatically on all the machines. This is trivial to do manual via management studio or run a script (in which case you need to have a valid connection to the server - catch 22).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using `System.Data.SqlClient.ConnectionStringBuilder`, rather than trying to build a `System.Data.SqlClient.ConnectionString` from a string.